# I have an array of 3d points. How to build Bézier surface from them? (using default flash 3d engine)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mxml, 3d-engine

So I have a new project that requires doing a lot of Bézier surface modeling. I am selecting a way for rendering data using flash. I need to be capabele to render a basier surface not using any big flash 3d engine in a maner as easy as possible a bezier surface that would cross for example such array of points:

```
{1,1,1}
{1,2,3}
{1,3,3}
{2,4,5}
{2,5,6}
{4,4,4}
```

So looks like an easy task for an engene I hope. So how to do such thing with flash?

BTW: (I use flex builder 3 to do flash development)

Comment: flash 10.1 is my build target. I use flex 4 sdk for compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out these interesting posts on the MiauMiau Labs Blog:

1. [NURBS in Flash (part 1)](http://labs.miaumiau.cat/?p=271)
2. [NURBS in Flash (part 2)](http://labs.miaumiau.cat/?p=338)

[image: NURBS in Flash]

HTH

Comment: Grate one!!!=) +1 and I woulg given +1 for point that its generaly pure AS no special libs like PV3d or Alternativa...

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog post of warping images using a 2d [bezier patch](http://fatlinesofcode.philipandrews.org/2011/02/20/warping-bitmaps-with-a-bezier-surface/) http://fatlinesofcode.philipandrews.org/2011/02/20/warping-bitmaps-with-a-bezier-surface/